# Media Queries not visible correctly for tablet view

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a web page and added media queries for that. It is working good for all the responsive but not working good for tablet(width: 768px). I am sharing the image below.

```
[Image][1]
```

**My html**

```
<div class="container-fluid service">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 margin" style="padding-top: 20px;margin-left: 45px;">
        <div class="row s1">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <h4 class="text-right design" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 24px; font-family: Titillium Web Semibold;color: #002A7B;line-height: 1">Emerging Markets<br>Strategy</h4>
                <p class="cnt1 text-right">Market penetration or New Product Introduction services to accelerate success in emerging markets</p>
                <input type="button" class="button" href="Product-Realization-Services.php" target="_blank" value="View More" style="float: right">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
                <img src="images/emerging market strategy.jpg" alt="Product Realization" style="height: 200px;padding-top: 12px;padding-bottom: 10%">   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**text.css**

@media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {

```
    .iconlist li {
        font-family: 'open sans'; 
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 12px!important;
        line-height: 1.2!important
    }

    .core {

        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .image {

        width: 100%;
        height: 150px!important;
    }

    .top h1{
        font-size: 24px!important;
        top: 15%!important;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .top span h1{
        font-size: 18px!important;
    } 
    .s1 img {
        height: 150px!important;
        padding-top: 50%!important;
        display: none;
    }
    .s1 {
        height: 170px!important;
    }

    .design{
        padding-top: 20px;
        font-size: 18px!important;
        font-family: Titillium Web Semibold;
        color: #002A7B;
        line-height: 1;
        text-align: justify-all!important;
    }
    .cnt {
        font-size: 13px!important;
        text-align: justify-all;
        color: #686868;
        line-height: 1.2!important;
    }

    .button {
        height: 30px!important;
        width: auto;
        float: left!important;
        font-size: 10px!important;
    }
    .design {
        font-size: 15px!important;
        float: left!important;
        text-align: left!important;
    }
    .cnt1 {
        font-size: 12px!important;
        text-align: justify-all!important;
        float: left!important;
        text-align: left!important;
    }
    .para {

        font-size: 16px!important;
        color: #002A7B;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web Semibold';
    }
    .services {
        padding-top: 0!important;
        margin-left: 0!important;
    }
    .margin {
        margin-left: 0!important;   
    }

    .one {
        font-family: 'open sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 13px!important;
        color: black;
        font-weight: none;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .two {

        font-family: 'Titillium Web Semibold';
        font-size: 13px!important;
        color: #061835;
    }

     .s1 img {
        float: right!important;
        position: inherit!important;
    }
}
```

**I am not able to get why it is not working correctly for tablet mode. For tablet alternative text and images be right** 
Thank You in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this hope it will help you

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 margin" style="padding-top: 20px;margin-left: 45px;">
        <div class="row s1">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <h4 class="text-right design" style="padding-top: 20px; font-size: 24px; font-family: Titillium Web Semibold;color: #002A7B;line-height: 1">Emerging Markets<br>Strategy</h4>
                <p class="cnt1 text-right">Market penetration or New Product Introduction services to accelerate success in emerging markets</p>
                <input type="button" class="button" href="Product-Realization-Services.php" target="_blank" value="View More" style="float: right">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <img src="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/img/bs-themes.png" alt="Product Realization">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    .margin {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .iconlist li {
        font-family: 'open sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 12px!important;
        line-height: 1.2!important
    }
    .core {
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    .image {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px!important;
    }
    .top h1 {
        font-size: 24px!important;
        top: 15%!important;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .top span h1 {
        font-size: 18px!important;
    }
    .s1 img {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .s1 {
        height: 170px!important;
    }
    .design {
        padding-top: 20px;
        font-size: 18px!important;
        font-family: Titillium Web Semibold;
        color: #002A7B;
        line-height: 1;
        text-align: justify-all!important;
    }
    .cnt {
        font-size: 13px!important;
        text-align: justify-all;
        color: #686868;
        line-height: 1.2!important;
    }
    .button {
        height: 30px!important;
        width: auto;
        float: left!important;
        font-size: 10px!important;
    }
    .design {
        font-size: 15px!important;
        float: left!important;
        text-align: left!important;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .cnt1 {
        font-size: 12px!important;
        text-align: justify-all!important;
        float: left!important;
        text-align: left!important;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .para {
        font-size: 16px!important;
        color: #002A7B;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web Semibold';
    }
    .services {
        padding-top: 0!important;
        margin-left: 0!important;
    }
    .margin {
        margin-left: 0!important;
    }
    .one {
        font-family: 'open sans';
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 13px!important;
        color: black;
        font-weight: none;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .two {
        font-family: 'Titillium Web Semibold';
        font-size: 13px!important;
        color: #061835;
    }
    .s1 img {
        float: right!important;
        position: inherit!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude I am way down there and if it works just mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the same media breaks as used by [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).

In any case, it is helpful to read and get the general idea of how it is done.

Basically, if you have a view that is smallest than you set up the break to be 'less than' some width. After that, each break should be 'greater than or equal' to some specified width otherwise you will get breaks overlaping.